# How to host full Vue app-, .NET Core API- and MariaDB stack in the cloud?

Tags: .net, vue.js, mariadb, cloud, web-hosting

So I want a free or cheap way to host a Vue web app, .NET Core API and MariaDB. It's for non-commercial use. The purpose is to create a portfolio web site about myself and my projects when I look for jobs. So it has to be public ofcourse. I don't have my own server so I can't host it on my own. Plus I don't want to be hacked.

Which are the best free/cheap services available for the stack mentioned above? Would be easier if I could host everything in one place/service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think virtual private server is best for you, OVH offers one for 6USD/month, without VAT (cheapest from their portfolio). Linux operating systems are for free (.NET works there), windows is payed. If u are ok with terminal use, u dont even need any 'control panel' like plesk, which is not for free.

Comment: Taking a look now.

Comment: Where is the 6USD offer? Can you link it?

Comment: Looks really interesting.

Comment: The build time of the vue application will be a bit longer, but otherwise it will be ok.